# How to configure TripleHead2Go in my Linux machine?

Tags: linux, xorg, multi-monitor, display-settings

Do I need any drivers or special configuration if I want to use a TripleHead2Go in my Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), or I just need to connect it, and it will just work, and it will be visible as one?

Answer (score 1):

This is a response from  Matrox Graphics

> Thank-you for contacting Matrox Graphics.  Your message has been
>   forwarded to us in the worldwide technical support team.
>
> Currently Matrox does not offer support for use of the GXM units under
>   Linux.  However, in many cases you should be able to connect two
>   displays of resolutions up to 1920x1080 or 3 displays of up to
>   resolution 1280x1024 to a TripleHead2Go unit.  Please note the
>   potential issues that could occur outlined in the following
>   paragraphs, and keep in mind that Matrox technical support can offer
>   limited guidance and no definitive answers regarding your system
>   running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
>
> Regardless of operating system, the Matrox GXM units appear to the
>   computer as a single display with a very wide resolution.  If trying
>   to use these units under Linux, we would recommend that you use a
>   graphics adapter that is already proven to work under Windows or Mac
>   OS (http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/compatibility/gxm/home/ 
>   ).  Note the display resolution limits indicated for the graphics
>   cards in the compatibility information.  Most likely you will
>   experience the same limitations, though in some cases Linux could be
>   more restrictive than the values listed.
>
> A vital part of TripleHead2Go selection is that it must be matched to
>   the appropriate type of connectors on the computer and on the
>   displays.  For example, a TripleHead2Go cannot be connected to the
>   HDMI output of a computer (and adapters do not work).  Supported
>   connections are listed in the “Product Line” on the website:
>
> - http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/
>
> Maximum dual and triple-display resolutions limitations are imposed by
>   the operating system, the graphics card, and the drivers.  While
>   Matrox does not test operating systems beyond Microsoft Windows and
>   Mac OS X, the experiences of our customers indicates that the highest
>   potential triple-display resolutions would be 1360x768 per display in
>   most Linux distributions.  Similarly, the highest potential
>   dual-display resolutions would likely be 1920x1200 in most Linux
>   distributions.  In any case, you would want to ensure that the latest
>   display drivers appropriate for your graphics card and Linux
>   distribution are installed.
>
> There is no Matrox software available for Matrox GXMs under Linux. 
>   Most Matrox TripleHead2Go units can be configured (EDID setup) using a
>   compatible Windows computer and Matrox PowerDesk software for Windows.
>   The maximum triple-display resolutions that can be supported by saving
>   the desired EDIDs to our unit (using a compatible Windows computer)
>   are 3840x1024 (3x 1280x1024) or 4080x768 (3x 1360x768).  Assuming that
>   the graphics card and the Linux display drivers for your card will
>   accept the resolutions, this could help make the desired dual or
>   triple-wide resolutions available.
>
> Normally during startup the computer’s graphics adapter card and the
>   Linux operating system’s display drivers should detect the resolutions
>   that have been setup to the Matrox unit (the EDID information), and
>   then make those resolutions available for selection in your Linux
>   display controls.  If you have purchased a TripleHead2Go and are
>   trying to use it but the display resolutions are not working, our
>   technical support team can provide a document of sample modelines. 
>   These can be edited in the Xorg.conf file to see if the resolutions
>   can be made available.  Note that many current Linux distributions
>   (like Ubuntu ) do not use an Xorg.conf file by default, so there can
>   be challenges creating and getting the distribution to respond to the
>   content of an Xorg.conf file.
>
> Should you be considering purchasing a unit with the intention of
>   trying it, please inform yourself thoroughly about the return
>   policies.  If purchasing from shopmatrox.com, you can read the return
>   policies in the “customer service” section of the website.
>
> We hope the information here proves somehow helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I connected a tripplehead2go on to my Ubuntu 16.04LTS machine.
It works out of the box, the resolution I can select is: 3840x1024 pixel.
Changed the EDID setting from a on a osx machine, but I guess its not necessary.
BTW. OSX recognizes a max resolution of 7680 x 2048

Answer (score 0):

OK Matrox is the authority and i'm just a wannabe user. But I have different information to offer.

My current laptop 17-by0061st was the cheapest Hp laptop also refurbished that i could buy at the time because of personal constraints. I have ran and am running 3 monitors with Matrox triplehead2go DE in Ubuntu 18.04 and now 20.04.

I bought the th2g more than 10 years ago and used it in win XP all the way up to win 10 and then in 2 versions of Ubuntu. In Ubuntu i'm using no software to support the Matrox box. Ubuntu sees it as a single display and i get currently 3072x768 stretched across 3 Phillips 24" 1920x1080 (16.9) monitors (246E9QDSB).

No HDMI support? hum, call my configuration crazy but it works. I have a HDMI VGA adapter in the HDMI out of the laptop to the Matrox VGA in. Then out to dual band DVI-D input on the monitors. Earlier in my quest for higher resolution I used single band DVI-I which worked as well. Hope this helps.